# Laravel 4 / Intervention / Dropzone.js not working with some images

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js, intervention

I am using Laravel / Intervention / Dropzone.js to upload images to my site using Ajax. The problem I am having is that some images return an "Error: 500" when uploaded. The problem isn't the file size, or dimensions, I've tested both of those. The problem, I believe, is Lightroom. The images that fail to upload are images that I edited using Lightroom. Is there something I should be doing to the images (encoding, sending headers) that would be causing this. Everything else works fine. This is my code.

```
if(Input::hasFile('file-upload')) {

            $file = Input::file('file-upload'); 

            $key = Input::get('_uuid');
            $img = Image::make($file[0]);

            $img = Image::make($file[0])->widen(500, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });

            $img = Image::make($file[0])->heighten(1080, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });


            $fileName = Uuid::generate();
            $extenstion = $file[0]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileItself = $fileName . '.' . $extenstion;

            $path = "/uploads/" . $fileItself;

            $img->save(public_path($path));
        }
```

**Dropzone.js options**

```
Dropzone.options.newPostForm = {
    paramName: "file-upload",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: "",
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    clickable: "#file-upload",
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 20,
    maxFilesize: 30
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but can you post your dropzone.js options?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but here is how I did it:

```
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);


    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
```